# AngularJS: Error Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is wrong with this code? I expect to see the value of 1 being printed in the console but instead it throws an error stating that self.list[0] is undefined???

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('notesApp', [])
        .controller('MainCtrl', ['ItemService', function(ItemService) {
            var self = this;
            self.list = function() {
                return ItemService.list();
            };

            console.log(self.list[0].id); //<<-- why does it print undefined??

            self.add = function() {
                ItemService.add({
                    id: self.list().length + 1,
                    label: 'Item ' + self.list().length
                });
            };

        }])
        .factory('ItemService', [function() {
            var items = [
                {id: 1, label: 'Item 0'},
                {id: 2, label: 'Item 1'}
            ];
            return {
                list: function() {
                    return items;
                },
                add: function(item) {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            };



        }]);
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who answers. Also, was trying not to be so blunt but SO won't allow me to put a simple greeting at the start of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at this point `self.list` is a function!! When the following is executed,

```
self.list = function() {
   return ItemService.list();
};
```

As you are expecting a list there, *maybe* you need to execute the function -- something like

```
self.list = function() {
   return ItemService.list();
}();
```

Try simply!

```
console.log("see self.list=", self.list);
```